# View related branches in issue

Tags: github

On Github, if we go to a branch, and then look at the top right, we can links to related issues as in the screenshot below.

However, when I am in the issue, ie: `https://github.com/Noitidart/The-My-App/issues/88`. I don't see links to related branches. Is it possible to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blue label `View 88` doesn't represent issue, it represents **pull request**.

For example, this [branch](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/automl_language_april_2019) on python-docs-samples has label `2091` which represents [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/pull/2091) pull request.

Comment: Thanks Dinko, is there anyway to get related issues on both sides? I name my branches prefixed with `issue_number-`

Comment: Normal workflow is to create new branch from master, naming it as you want with `feature-fix_something`, work on that branch, make commits and reference issue in pull request or in your commits. For example, commit message could go like `#88 - Fix styling` where #88 is issue that had problem with styling. Or you can have multiple fixes in branch if they are identical or share something in common.

Comment: Hi @Noitidart if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I was looking for something to get related branch into my issues. And related issues into my branches. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: Github has a concept of "pull requests". For example, [this](https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/2785) pull request references [this](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2730) issue in comments. Pull requests on github mean changes in some branch. If you cloned a project, worked on it, other person doesn't have to read all commits from the beginning of project. They just want additional commits you made when you cloned a project. This is concept of "Pull request".